# How to write/read a struct to/from a binary file in Swift?

Tags: swift, file, struct, binary, file-writing

Editing for clarity: Similar to how you can read/write a struct to a file in C using fwrite, I want to find the equivalent using Swift but have been running into dead ends and lack of documentation for weeks. I'm basically trying to find the Swift version of the following code in C (this code works fine). Essentially, the main final goal of my program is to take in a binary file that only contains information of multiple struct objects. I have/know the struct so I then just want to read binary from the file and read it in to a struct object in my program to use for later.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//#pragma pack(push)
//#pragma pack(1)
struct Creature {
    int8_t legs;
    int8_t eyes;
    int32_t hair;
};
//#pragma pack(push)

int main() {
    struct Creature grimace;
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(grimace));
    FILE* readfile;

    readfile = fopen("/Users/name/Desktop/code/testing.txt", "wb+");
    if (readfile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct Creature birthday = {6, 3, 258 };
    fwrite(&birthday, sizeof(birthday), 1, readfile);
    rewind(readfile);
    struct Creature shake;
    fread(&shake, sizeof(shake), 1, readfile);
 
   // birthday.hair = reverseByteOrder(birthday.hair);
     printf("Legs: %d Eyes: %d Hair: %d\n", shake.legs,
           shake.eyes, shake.hair);

    fclose(readfile);

    return 0;

}
```

Currently I'm trying to use File Handler to write binary data to the file and converting the struct to binary data but I am running into problems trying to convert the struct into a binary data object for writing and just setting up the file to write in general. I've tried InputStream as well with less results and FileHandler seems to be the closest to fwrite in C. I feel like this should be a relatively easy problem to solve but I am quite stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated tysm!

Comment: Unless you _really_ know what you're doing, you shouldn't serialize in-memory representations of structs to files, even in C, which will gladly give you that gun to shoot your foot off with. It's really really fragile, and will break any time you change the struct layout. It's better to serialize/deserialize it to some other representation like YAML, JSON, message pack, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Alexander says, don't do that. You should serialize your struct and write your serialized data to a file.

The Codable protocol makes serializing back and forth to JSON easy. You could use a binary plist file format if you want speed and data density, but that seems to be falling out of fashion.

Comment: the main thing is that I need to be able to read a binary file that I know only contains information of a struct (or multiple objects of a struct) and then be able to use the struct size and its individual components size to read the binary data from the file and assign it back to a struct. i'm testing out writing here as a precursor to reading but i don't think json will be useful in the further implementation. do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: You say "... I need to be able to... use the struct size and its individual components size to read the binary data from the file and assign it back to a struct..." What do you mean "use the struct size to read the binary data?"

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to map the contents of the struct as it is stored in memory directly back and forth to a binary file. That is considered an anti-pattern. It is not portable across different processor types and is fragile if your data structure changes at all. Don't do it that way.

Comment: You might look at using NSCoding, which would let you map your data to binary key/value pairs in a way that is platform-independent.

Comment: Ooh I see. It's not so much about writing but I'd essentially be taking in binary files that contain multiple objects of a struct type and I'd just want to be able to read through the file and read the data into a struct/multiple structs. The assumption I'm going off of here is that for this purpose the binary file will correspond directly to this struct type. So, similar to the way you can use fread and a pointer to a struct object to read the binary file into the struct and create an object in the program. I'll take a look at NSCoding instead of trying to do it directly, I appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, doing a binary read/write directly into/out of struct memory is bad practice because it locks you into specific internal binary representations of your data, which is not part of the contract with the compiler.